# How do I add NOT NULL columns to an SQL table but the existing entries have NULL values?

Tags: sql

I am still learning SQL so please bear with me. There is already an existing database table called `users`. Currently, it has the following columns:

```
userID (PRIMARY KEY)
username
email
password
```

Now, I need to add two more columns which are `staffID` and `phoneno` but the `staffID` has to be `NOT NULL`. I am trying to update the existing entries so that I can add the `staffID` column which is `NOT NULL`. Obviously, the existing/older entries don't have `staffID`. So, before I actually run the commands below, I want to ask if they are correct or if there is a better way to do this (because the database is not really mine -- I don't want to destroy it).

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD staffID int(11);

ALTER TABLE users
ADD phoneno int(11);

UPDATE users
SET staffID = ''
WHERE
   staffID IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN staffID int(11) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You can try for yourself e.g. here: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: SET staffID = '' should change to SET staffID = 0 as '' is not a valid int value. The exact syntax depends on the type os SQL server you are using which you haven't specified. But overall it looks good. Anyway none of this sentences is destructive..  :)